# Cannot install ActionBarSherlock: I follow through the first 5 minutes of this video: http://youtu.be/4GJ6yY1lNNY

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

Before I can even try to use ActionBarSherlock, I have errors in every project in the com.actionbarsherlock.widget package.

All of the errors seem to be of the type
`"Context cannot be resolved to a type"` or
`"The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (SuggestionsAdapter)"`

I've spent hours trying this on projects, reading stackoverflow questions, reading faq's, and I hate Eclipse and ABS right now.

I'm sure that this is something simple and dumb.

Can anyone help?

Note: I can fix a lot of the errors by importing `android.util.[TheNameOfWhateverTypeCan'tBeResolved]`, and that's what I did the first time around, but it didn't fix everything, and the project I tried to use ABS in didn't work.  However, I haven't read of anyone else needing to do that, ergo I'm guessing that there is some other fundamental problem that I'm missing.

Comment: I need to read better :\ Too many similar questions.

Comment: What is the Android version you built it against?

Comment: I built against Android API 17.

Comment: Not exactly sure, but you could try making sure you have the latest Android support libraries and also reinstalling the SDK.

Comment: I had a similar problem the first time I tried using ABS, but it was due to the fact that the JDK for the project was not selected for 1.5; but since it has been a breeze working with ABS. You can maybe check on that.

Comment: The Java Compiler is set for 1.6
Is that wrong?